# Correct Syntax for using LEFT in a ROW Statement in VB

Tags: vb.net, row

I know this seems like a very elementary issue and forgive me, but I wasn't able to find the syntax.

For some reason VB doesn't like this syntax, what am I missing?

drNewPat.pzip5 = Left(row("zip"), 5)

I use a similar statement using Trim and it works fine.

drNewPat.gname = "Group Name: " + Trim(row("gname"))

Thanks again in advance!

Comment: What is it you are trying to do, trim only removes white space from the beginning and end of your text. If you want to get the first 5 characters then why don't you use .SubString() if Left does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Net provides all sorts of handy `String` methods. Ont to get to know is `.Substring`. Old vb6 methods are usually not as good.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim row As DataRow
    row = dt.Rows(0)
    Dim s = row("zip").ToString.Substring(0, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, I like this.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the MID() and worked...not sure why Left is not a valid function - but moving on, thanks.

drNewPat.pzip5 = Mid(row("zip"), 1, 5)

Comment: It was preferring the Left property of a window (as in Top, Left, Bottom, Right) to the Left function from Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when I used it in a form. At first, I changed it to Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left per Google results. It worked for a few days, but this morning it stopped working somehow after I imported Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Out of bewilderment and instinct, I keyed in Strings.Left and it works. It seems Left is used probably by default for "Gets or sets the distance, in pixels, in between..."; therefore, for string operation, it needs to be called out differently. BTW I'm just an amateur programmer.